# How can i set some text in a dynamic text field to italic in Adobe Animate?

Tags: flash, adobe

I need to write some parts of a dynamic text field in italic. Let's say i want to write "text" in my code to italic. How would i do that?

```
this.instance_name.text = "This is some text.";
```

Comment: Forgot to include important information: it's a html5 animation.

Answer (score 0):

Untested for *"`it's a html5 animation`"* but you can try using [htmlText](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html#htmlText) property of [`textField`](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html):

```
this.instance_name.htmlText = "This is some <i>text</i>.";
```